# Getting a column from a Table while using info from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to use the Primary Key of the Employee table that exists in the Projects table to look up the employee question. Then once I have the name I wish to place the name into the next column over.(Examples of the tables are included).

Can this be done in only SQL?

Should this be done in only SQL?

What would you recommend if not SQL?

Projects Table:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Yovfu33LcMeXFhTmZQR19Zenc/view?usp=sharing

```
Cus_Rep  Cus_Rep_Name
7        NULL
33       NULL
7        NULL
32       NULL
45       NULL
45       NULL
32       NULL
32       NULL
3        NULL
1        NULL
2        NULL
2        NULL
2        NULL
```

Employee Table:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Yovfu33LcMVE1YNWxrWGVDR3c/view?usp=sharing

```
ID_Num FullName
0      LeRoy Jenkins
1      Samuel Oak
2      Some One
```

Comment: You  can inline table screenshots using image button

Comment: Please include your data as text. We cant copy/paste from image.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @TheGameiswar New user cant append images

Comment: oh Thanks for that ,i don't know that

Comment: Your question isnt clear. What is your expected result?

Comment: replace nulls with names with the corresponding number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an update statement like this. This will link your tables and update Projects with the value from Employee

```
UPDATE p
SET p.Cus_Rep_Name = e.FullName
FROM Projects p
JOIN Employee e
ON p.Cus_Rep = c.ID_Num
```

Comment: I had misnamed the column. It worked Thank you for all your help.